# Traefik Best Practices/Capabilities For Dynamic Vanity Domain Certificates

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, ssl-certificate, reverse-proxy, traefik

I'm looking for guidance on the proper tools/tech to accomplish what I assume is a fairly common need.

If there exists a web service: `https://www.ExampleSaasWebService.com/` and customers can add **vanity domains/subdomains to white-label or resell the service and replace the domain name with their own, there needs to be a reverse proxy to terminate vanity domains TLS traffic and route it to the statically defined (HTTPS) back-end service on the non-vanity original domain** (there is essentially one "back-end" server somewhere else on the internet, not the local network, that accepts all incoming traffic no matter the incoming domain). Essentially:

- "Customer A" could setup an A/CNAME record to `VanityProxy.ExampleSaasWebService.com` (the host running Traefik) from `example.customerA.com`.
- "Customer B" could setup an A/CNAME record to `VanityProxy.ExampleSaasWebService.com` (the host running Traefik) from `customerB.com` and `www.customerB.com`.
- etc...

I (surprisingly) haven't found anything that does this out of the box, but looking at [Traefik](https://containo.us/traefik/) (2.x) I'm seeing some promising capabilities and it seems like the most capable tool to accomplish this. Primarily because of the Let's Encrypt integration and the ability to reconfigure without a restart of the service.

I initially considered AWS's native certificate management and load balancing, but I see there is a [limit of ~25 certificates per load balancer](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=841342) which seems like a non-starter. Presumably there could be thousands of vanity domains in place at any time.

Some of my Traefik specific questions:

1. Am I correct in understanding that you can get away without explicitly provisioning a generated list of explicit vanity domains to produce TLS certificates for in the config files? They can be determined on-the-fly and provisioned from Let's Encrypt based on the headers of the incoming requests/SNI?

   - E.g. If a request comes to `www.customerZ.com` and there is not yet a certificate for that domain name, one can be generated on the fly?
   - I found this note on [the OnDemand flag in the v1.6 docs](https://docs.traefik.io/v1.6/user-guide/examples/#ondemand-option-with-http-challenge), but I'm struggling to find the equivalent documentation in the (2.x) docs.
2. Using AWS services, how can I easily share "state" (config/dynamic certificates that have already been created) between multiple servers to share the load? My initial thought was EFS, but I see EFS shared file system may not work because of a dependency on file change watch notifications not working on NFS mounted file systems?

   - It seemed like it would make sense to provision an AWS NLB (with a static IP and an associated DNS record) that delivered requests to a fleet of 1 or more of these Traefik proxies with a universal configuration/state that was safely persisted and kept in sync.
3. Like I mentioned above, this seems like a common/generic need. Is there a configuration file sample or project that might be a good starting point that I overlooked? I'm brand new to Traefik.
4. When routing requests to the back-end service, the original `Host` name will be identifiable still [somewhere in the headers](https://docs.traefik.io/middlewares/headers/#hostsproxyheaders)? I assume it can't remain in the Host header as the back-end recieves requests to an HTTPS hostname as well.

I will continue to experiment and post any findings back here, but I'm sure someone has setup something like this already -- so just looking to not reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Tracked down that "onDemand" option was unfortunately removed in 2.x: https://github.com/containous/traefik/issues/2212#issuecomment-413157209

Answer (score 1):

I managed to do this with Caddy. It's very important that you configure the ask,interval and burst to avoid possible DDoS attacks.

Here's a simple reverse proxy example:

```
# https://caddyserver.com/docs/caddyfile/options#on-demand-tls
{
    # General Options
    debug

    on_demand_tls {
        # will check for "?domain=" return 200 if domain is allowed to request TLS
        ask "http://localhost:5000/ask/"
        interval 300s
        burst 1
    }
}

# TODO: use env vars for domain name? https://caddyserver.com/docs/caddyfile-tutorial#environment-variables
qrepes.app {
    reverse_proxy localhost:5000
}

:443 {
    reverse_proxy localhost:5000

    tls {
        on_demand
    }
}
```